# What is the file type of Redux Form's file input when uploading images?

Tags: redux, redux-form

I'm trying to use [Redux Form's file input](http://redux-form.com/5.3.1/#/examples/file?_k=gffvms) to allow users to upload images. I'm able to set it up with the rest of my fields in my form. The jpg file that gets passed down to my actions looks something like this:

```
{
  userImages: {
    value: [
      {
        lastModified: 1467575553000,
        lastModifiedDate: Sun Jul 03 2016 15:52:33 GMT-0400 (EDT),
        name: "hero_bg.jpg",
        size: 96826,
        type : "image/jpeg",
        webkitRelativePath: ""
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I'm using [Cloudinary to post to their API](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_images#uploading_with_a_direct_call_to_the_api) and upload the image. However, when I pass userImages.value[0] as my file, it's returning to me a 400 bad request error which is leading me to believe that it's an issue with the file information that being passed.

In the Cloudinary documentation they accept the following file types:

> Can be the actual data (byte array buffer), the Data URI (Base64
>   encoded), a remote FTP, HTTP or HTTPS URL of an existing file, or an
>   S3 URL (of a whitelisted bucket).

So don't think the image prop being passed down fits any one of these.

Here's my action:

```
//...

export function putImage(props) {

  console.log(props)

  const cloudinaryURL = 'https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/<my_name_here>/image/upload';

  const image =
    axios.post(cloudinaryURL, {
      file: props,
      upload_preset: 'test123'
    })
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log(response)
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error)
    })

  return {
    type: PUT_IMAGE,
    payload: image,
  }
}
```

Am I correctly handling this file input / jpg upload through Redux Form? Any and all help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: did you get success?

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue with axios and can't find any answer about that problem, then i switched to superagent and it works fine.

https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent

```
  import request from 'superagent';

  let upload = request.post(CLOUDINARY.UPLOAD_URL)
    .field('upload_preset', CLOUDINARY.UPLOAD_PRESET)
    .field('file', file); // file to upload

  upload.end((err, response) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err); // error handling
    }

    if (response.body.secure_url !== '') {
      console.log(response.body.secure_url); // cloudinary image url
    }
  });
```